# LOW_PRIORITY during update on Innodb Slow down performance

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have faced issued like slowness and database locking when use  LOW_PRIORITY during update on Innodb. Have anyone faced this or there is any documentation in Mysql for Innodb?

Comment: Database locking? I think you mean table locking.. But InnoDB doesnt table lock InnoDB uses row locks..

Comment: I think InnoDB ignores `LOW_PRIORITY`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `UPDATE` statement.  There may be something else causing what you are seeing.  (Often it the lack of the optimal composite index.)

Comment: UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY `deviceVols` SET 
`VolName` = '10.9.1.14', 
`type`= 'siris', 
`compressRatio` = '3.46',
`dedup` = '0',
`snapCount` = '70',
`firstSnap` = '2017-01-31 19:11:08',
`lastSnap` = '2017-05-04 10:00:20',
`lastUpdated` = NOW(),
`lastError` = '',
`HIRSuccess` = '',
`HIRError` = '',
`continuumID` = ''
WHERE `deviceID` = '79562' AND `zfsPath` = 'homePool/home/agents/10.9.1.14' LIMIT 1;
Runs for o to 3 seconds, 1K in 1 hour